# The electron crashed event of render process is triggered too late?

Tags: javascript, electron, chromium

#### Problem Description:

I use `process.crash()` or `process.abort()` in the render process.
And it took a long time to receive the crash event.

This can cause a bad user experience：

If for some reason a crash occurs in a rendering process, the user needs to wait a long time（about 20 - 30 seconds） on the unresponsive page, and after a long time The callback for `webContents.addListener('crashed'` is called and then the developer can do something.

#### My exploration：

I search in the electron source code and find：

```
void WebContents::RenderProcessGone(base::TerminationStatus status) {
  Emit("crashed", status == base::TERMINATION_STATUS_PROCESS_WAS_KILLED);
}
```

is this the right function which emit `crashed` event to `win.webContents`？

Maybe it is related to some chromium's processing

Limited by my level of knowledge, I am not very clear about this part.

#### Some schematic code：

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({
   // some config...
});


win.webContents.addListener('crashed', () => {
  // This callback is triggered too late  
  if (!win.isDestroyed()) {
    win.close();
  }
});
```

Actually，The application is much more complicated.

#### Wanted：

I want to know why it takes a long time from `process.crash()` or `process.abort()` called to The `crashed` event emitted ? What did the electron or the chromium do during that time?

And I want to know if There is any solution to solve this problem(get the `crashed` event as quick as possible) ?